# Watir Errno::EHOSTDOWN: Host is down

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I installed watir-webdriver and copied chromedriver in path(/usr/bin) folder. It worked fine for me. But when I did the same on an another machine, it threw an error: `Errno::EHOSTDOWN: Host is down - connect(2)`.

Is there anything that i am missing to configure?

I am using Mac os x 10.6.8, X-code 4.2, ruby 1.9.3

The stack trace:

```
Errno::EHOSTDOWN: Host is down - connect(2)
from /Users/pakku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:63:in `connect_nonblock'
from /Users/pakku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:63:in `listening?'
from /Users/pakku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:23:in `block in connected?'
from /Users/pakku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:87:in `with_timeout'
from /Users/pakku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:23:in `connected?'
from /Users/pakku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:49:in `start'
from /Users/pakku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:15:in `initialize'
from /Users/pakku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `new'
from /Users/pakku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `for'   
from /Users/pakku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'   
from /Users/pakku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'    
from (irb):3:in `new'
from (irb):3
from /Users/pakku/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: At what point did you get this exception? Is there a full stacktrace?

Comment: @JustinKo
require "watir-webdriver"  =>true. 
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome (When this line is executed, the error is produced.)